# Converting UTM coordinates to Lat/Long in R

Tags: r, data-conversion, utm

I am trying to convert UTM coordinates (Easting and Northing) to Lat/Long using R. A sample of my data is as follows:

| dx | dy |
| --- | --- |
| -17.551 | 17.062 |
| -4.947 | 2.336 |
| -17.265 | 3.956 |
| -12.157 | -2.043 |

Here is my code:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggmap)
    library(maps)
    library(rgdal)
    library(ggplot2)
    
    east<-as.numeric(ddata$dy)
    north<-as.numeric(ddata$dx)
    utm <- SpatialPoints(cbind(east,north), 
                 proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=59 +datume=WGS84 "))
    spTransform(utm, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

However, I'm not getting correct lat/long values, as the data is collected from New Zealand so the latitude, longitude values must be from this location. How can I correct this code to generate the right values of lat and long?

Here is a link to my data:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X8pPFxV8ZBl1gAWOeYASG0BsnryovpyE/view?usp=sharing

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please paste sample data in the question; use `dput(ddata)` or use `dput(head(ddata))` so that the question becomes reproducible to allow answers to be verified. [MRE] provides useful guidance.

Comment: How many rows are in `ddata`? Might it be 0?

Comment: Could you include the packages you are using in the question?

Comment: Can you include the reference from which you collected the data? Are the  Eastings and Northings defined? Check your assignments, typically longitude is the equated with the x-axis  i.e. `east <- as.numeric(ddata$dx)`.

Comment: Is there metadata for the variables in your data? i.e. an explanation of what the variables represent. Just checked definition of UTM and it seems as if latitude in the southern hemisphere is defined with positive values, so previous comment about negative latitude values withdrawn. Do you know what the `x ` and  `y` variables in the original dataset represent?

Answer (score 1):

This may help...

Data is the first 6 rows and columns from the link provided in the question.
Have used `x` variable as longitude and `y` as latitude.
A search on the internet revealed a crs for New Zealand to be 2193: New Zealand  Transverse Mercator which at least puts the co-ordinates in New Zealand. But you'd need to confirm that.
The co-ordinates seem to be very close to each other so all points overlap at the scale plotted - I've not experimented with this.

https://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/datums-projections-and-heights/projections/new-zealand-transverse-mercator-2000

```r
library(sf)
library(tmap)

df_sf <- st_as_sf(x = df,                         
                  coords = c("x", "y"),
                  crs =     2193)

data("World")
nz <-  World[World$name == "New Zealand", ]

tm_shape(nz, projection = "wgs84") +
  tm_polygons()+
  tm_grid()+
  tm_shape(df_sf, projection = "wgs84")+
  tm_dots("id", size = 0.5)
```

[image]

**To convert UTM x, y coordinates into longitude and latitude**

```r
library(proj4)

# Find the projection proj4 description of the coordinate reference system (espg 2193)
#  I've used information from this link:
# https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nzgd2000-new-zealand-transverse-mercator-2000/proj4/

proj4 <- "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "

# From the source data extract the x, y coordinates of the UTM
x_y <- df[, 1:2]

# Transform the data
lon_lat <- project(x_y, proj4, inverse = TRUE)

# convert to a data frame
data.frame(lon = lon_lat$x, lat = lon_lat$y)

#>        lon       lat
#> 1 132.3681 -71.33355
#> 2 132.3685 -71.33371
#> 3 132.3686 -71.33375
#> 4 132.3690 -71.33391
#> 5 132.3692 -71.33402
#> 6 132.3689 -71.33392
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 423:428, x = c(1455320.99774103, 1455303.44574159, 
                                         1455298.49781114, 1455281.23215399, 1455269.07477818, 1455280.83403596
), y = c(5131693.29609067, 5131710.35870728, 5131712.69526321, 
         5131716.65168218, 5131714.60800342, 5131734.86699543), date = c("2019-03-12 00:02:00", 
                                                                         "2019-03-12 00:04:49", "2019-03-12 00:07:37", "2019-03-12 00:10:24", 
                                                                         "2019-03-12 00:13:19", "2019-03-12 00:16:06"), dx = c(-17.5519994448405, 
                                                                                                                               -4.94793045334518, -17.2656571443658, -12.1573758164886, 11.7592577852774, 
                                                                                                                               16.6252572031226), dy = c(17.0626166081056, 2.33655592985451, 
                                                                                                                                                         3.95641897153109, -2.04367875494063, 20.2589920070022, -29.7507258579135
                                                                                                                               )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. How can we extract longitude-latitude values?

Comment: ok. How can we extract the latitude and longitude values using this script?

Comment: Ah I understand; have added additional code to extract longitude and latitude into a separate dataframe.